# ImportError: Could not import settings 'mysite.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named mysite.settings

Tags: python, django, apache, python-2.7

editing to try and troubleshoot with first answer.

Now I am getting 403 forbidden.  This is what I have:

```
<VirtualHost ip:80>
    ServerAdmin admin
    ServerName name
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/django/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py

<Directory /home/django/mysite/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
     Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have a user created "django" /home/django and all subdirectories have permissions of "django".  This is how it should be, correct?

I am running django 1.6.2

/home/django contains mysite, and '/home/django/mysite' contains manage.py.  /home/django/mysite/mysite/ contains, init, urls, and wsgi.py.

wsgi.py contains:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/home/django/mysite')

os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] =  "mysite.settings"

# NOTICE: the following may only work well in django version 1.5 1.6
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

What am I doing wrong?  Why am I getting forbidden? :(  Does wsgi.py need to be user/group apache?

If it matters,  Server version: Apache/2.2.15

Could it possibly have anything to do with mod_userdir.c?

Comment: Support for mod_pyhton is deprecated. Django.core.handlers.modpython shouldnt exist unless you are using an older version of django. I suggest you switch back to mod wsgi and let us help you configure that instead

Comment: hey can you check out updated post?, using mod_wsgi, and did recommendations of first answer.

Answer (score 3):

I usually write it in `wsgi.py` using `mod_wsgi`

configuration in `*.conf` (Apache version >= 2.4):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAdmin example@example.com

        Alias /media/ /home/tu/blog/media/
        Alias /static/ /home/tu/blog/collected_static/

        <Directory /home/tu/blog/media>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/tu/blog/collected_static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/tu/blog/blog/wsgi.py

        <Directory /home/tu/blog/blog>
        <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
        </Files>
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**if you use Apache 2.2 use**

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

instead of

```
Require all granted
```

wsgi.py (depends on your django version)

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/path/to/project/')

os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] =  "project.settings"

# NOTICE: the following may only work well in django version 1.5 1.6
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

That is, regard your django project as a python package, `sys.path` used to tell python where the project is.

Comment: Thank you for replying.  Have struggled with this so much.  Now I'm getting 403 forbidden errors.  I updated main post with everything I have, can you take a look?  Thanks sooo much!

Comment: As stated in the answer, this is a solution for Apache 2.4. For Apache 2.2, use `Order allow,deny Allow from all` instead of `Require all granted`.